# Unfortunately radio has stopped

Tags: cellular-radio

Suddenly the built in radio application cannot be started anymore. I do not know if I changed something, but I couldn't find how to fix it.

**What is the possible cause?**

PS: I did a soft reset, and I cleared its data and cache.

Comment: Failure for the radio to work and you haven't touched the system, and altered it in any way, and the problem persists even after cache clearing and data clearing, you might have to do a factory reset since you're running out of options. If it persists still, that's a system error and you need to flash your phone

Comment: @thally ace - I am not sure that I did not change anything in between. That is why i wonder what to check.

Comment: If factory reset won't fix that. Because it seems the cause for that isn't well structured and you may need to reset it. You have just no option other than flashing